# Ruby/Rails - Is an "events" method on my user model such a bad idea?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rolify

I'm developing an application in which users participate in one or more events and so can be said to "have" events based on the role(s) they occupy within those events. I'm using Rolify to associate users with events. Rolify forms the association between a user and an event based on the role they occupy within that event. Rolify is more concerned with returning data about a user's roles but doesn't care about the event within which the user has the role and so won't return data about the event (apart from its ID).

So, I can write a method like this:

```
@user.roles
```

and get all roles associated with the user.

One such role looks like this:

```
 => #<Role id: 1, name: "admin", resource_id: 1, resource_type: "Event", created_at: "2014-12-19 04:00:33", updated_at: "2014-12-19 04:00:33">
```

What I want to be able to do is to say

```
@user.events(roleName)
```

and get all events associated with roleName.

Obviously, I cannot do this given only what's available to me via Rolify, so I've created a method on my user model to help:

```
  def events roleName=nil
    events_list = []

    self.roles.each do |role|
      unless roleName.nil?
        if role.name == roleName && role.resource_type == "Event"
          events_list.push(role.resource_id)
        end
      else
        events_list.push(role.resource_id)
      end
    end
    Event.find(events_list)
  end
```

My concerns are that

1. This method somehow violates the single responsibility principle.
2. This method requires multiple database calls in order to finally get the events--one to roles, then another to events. (I'm inexperienced with this sort of thing, so I'm not sure just how bad it really is.)

Is there a better way to get a user's events while keeping my Rolify role setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, that's a bad idea when you have the following possibility in Rails:

Add this in your User model:

```
has_many :events, through: :roles, source: :resource, source_type: 'Event'
```

That way `user.events` will return all of a user's events. And for a specific role's events, you could:

```
user.events.where(roles: {name: role_name})
```

[Lastly, a suggestion: don't use camel-case names for methods, variables, or symbols.](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide)

Comment: This is throwing a syntax error that reads: "ArgumentError: Unknown key: :member. Valid keys are: :class_name, :class, :foreign_key, :validate, :autosave, :table_name, :before_add, :after_add, :before_remove, :after_remove, :extend, :primary_key, :dependent, :as, :through, :source, :source_type, :inverse_of, :counter_cache, :join_table"

Comment: Yeah, that was a typo. The key should be `source` - I've updated my response.

Comment: Also, thanks for the link to the Ruby style guide. I'll definitely work with a view to it. I'm currently reading Practical Object-Oriented Design in Ruby and am thinking the two will go hand-in-hand.

Comment: I'm curious--what if I need to access this method from multiple places within my view? Is it OK to write this in my view? user.events.where(roles: {name: role_name})

Comment: No. That will fire a database query and slow down the rendering speed of your view. Remember: data should be sent to the view, already generated - otherwise the speed suffers when the view has to generate data itself. You could do the same thing in the controller, store the value in an instance variable, and then use that instance variable (already gotten value) in the view.

Comment: ACk! Now I'm confused. I'm not sure of how to get the value into my controller as an instance variable. I mean, I'm not sure just where it should go. I could try the show method: @my_events = @user.events.where(roles: {name: "Event"}), but that seems to be failing.

Comment: You probably don't have a role named 'Event'. You need to do something like this: http://www.codeshare.io/K5AF7